# Alter exisitng int column to identity in sybase

Tags: sybase, identity, identity-column

Sybase 12.5

I have an existing table in production that needs it's PK int column to be altered such that it is auto populated - when the table was created it would ideally have had the ID column created as an Identity.  This ID column is a foreign key in multiple other tables so deleting the table and starting again isn't an option.  Problem is, I can't set the PK as an IDENTITY, and creating a temp column with the current values and copying these to a new IDENTITY column is also failing.

As the ID column is already populated, I can't simply turn this column into an IDENTITY (at least, I haven't found any SQL that will do this).

I have created a copy of the table, with an additional column holding the current PK value (division_id_tmp).

```
CREATE TABLE division_tmp
(
   division_id int IDENTITY NOT NULL 
   division_id_tmp int,      
   description varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   is_active tinyint DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
)
```

When i try to enter a datascript from the original table

```
INSERT INTO division_tmp
(description,is_active,division_id_tmp,division_id) 
VALUES 
('TEST',1,36,34)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Explicit value specified for identity field in table 'division_tmp' 
when 'SET IDENTITY_UPDATE' is OFF.
```

If I run the statement:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT division_tmp OFF
```

The statement executes without complaint, but attempts to insert the datascript result in the same error as above.  If I run the statement

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ac_division_lookup_awd ON
```

I get the error

```
Error: Unable to 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT' for table '**division_tmp**' because 
IDENTITY_INSERT or IDENTITY_UPDATE is already ON for the table '**division**' in 
database 'preserve'.
```

I can't be the first person who's experienced this problem?  Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Or, to put it more clearly - I have column A, which is an int PK.  I need to create column B, make it an identity column and populate it with the values of A.

Comment: There is one other option round this - there are only about 7 users who will insert into this table, the chances of them doing a simultaneous insert are small.  I can drop the identity, reinstate the PK and on insert select max(division_id) + 1.  It's a dirty fix, but attempting to re-organise the keys throughout the schema is a lot riskier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it.  Think the underlying issue is I am a tool.

Getting confused between:

```
IDENTITY_INSERT
```

and

```
IDENTITY_UPDATE
```

So, what I need to do is:

```
alter table division add division_id_tmp int IDENTITY not null 
SET IDENTITY_UPDATE division ON
update division set division_id_tmp = division_id
SET IDENTITY_UPDATE division OFF
alter table division drop division_id
EXEC sp_rename 
    @objname = 'division.division_id_tmp', 
    @newname = 'division_id', 
    @objtype = 'COLUMN'
```

Job done!